# Why isn't array_unique with SORT_REGULAR working as expected?

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I'm trying to get to one array that don't have duplicate values for a specific field in an array of objects. I've merged two array's of objects together and am using `$unique = array_unique($merged, SORT_REGULAR)` to remove any duplicate values that the merged array might have.

Unfortunately I cannot get a result of one array without the duplicate value (let's say for the `email` field) as the resulting array still contains two instances of one email.

It's my understanding that using the `SORT_REGULAR` flag is supposed to catch that but it obviously doesn't. Can someone explain why, and perhaps what I'm missing to do it right?

The two objects:

`$tracks = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Trak')->findByGrace($arrayNum);`

`$grades = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Grade')->findByGrace($arrayGrad);`

How I merge them:

`$merge = array_merge($tracks, $grades);`

Using Array Unique:

`$unique = array_unique($merge, SORT_REGULAR);`

My output for `$tracks, $merge & $unique` are as follows. They each start exactly the same way (as it uses the first object from $tracks) and the culprit that has the duplicate email is the first instance in the object. I hope this helps:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AppBundle\Entity\Trak Object
        (
            [id:AppBundle\Entity\Trak:private] => 657
            [active:AppBundle\Entity\Trak:private] => 1
            [sid:AppBundle\Entity\Trak:private] => 1554
            [firstName:AppBundle\Entity\Trak:private] => X
            [lastName:AppBundle\Entity\Trak:private] => Y
            [title:AppBundle\Entity\Trak:private] => ISW
            [organization:AppBundle\Entity\Trak:private] => Self Employed
            [email:AppBundle\Entity\Trak:private] => XY@gmail.com
            ..........
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Comment: Show us ingoing, and results. Otherwise its just hearsay.

Comment: _two array's of objects_ ???

Comment: The code you provide does not show what those variables contain. Please provide sample data.

Comment: I'll edit with some sample data.

Comment: Some `print_r($tracks);` `print_r($merge);` `print_r($unique);` would go a long way here ;)

Comment: I've provided some sample data, hopefully that helps

Comment: Quick test: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6025ec0f0187d42cceceb9889766a7d8146670d0

Comment: @biziclop, that's neat but that's why I'm confused why it's not working for me...

Comment: Maybe you could `serialize` the two supposedly same items and compare the serialized strings if they are different.

Comment: oh wait a minute, is it because the entities are different? One entity being `AppBundle\Entity\Trak` and another `AppBundle\Entity\Grade`???

Comment: but no, wouldn't that be what `SORT_REGULAR` is for?

Comment: It seems you won: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc67370b6811e356d8e81124b074dcdc81c74659
You should answer your own question to help other people.

Comment: Also you could do something similar: `foreach( $merged as $o ) $merged2[ $o->someUniqueKey ] = $o;`